# xcolor: Convert color names of e.g. svgnames and dvipsnames to corresponding rgb value

Tags: color, conversion, convert

How can I get the corresponding rgb color of `xcolor`'s color names like `svgnames` or `dvipsnames`?

**Example:**

How can I convert `svgnames`'s `DarkGreen` to its corresponding rgb value?

Comment: extracting and converting are different things. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `xcolor` package has a macro `\extractcolorspecs` that does exactly this. It also tells you the current color model.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\extractcolorspecs{DarkGreen}{\myColorModel}{\myColor}
DarkGreen is \myColor\ in model \myColorModel
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way is to simply look it up in `xcolor`'s `xcolor.dtx` file, for example from http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.dtx

The file contains:

```
%<*svgnames>
\preparecolorset{rgb}{}{}{%
[...]
DarkBlue,0,0,.545;%
DarkCyan,0,.545,.545;%
DarkGoldenrod,.72,.525,.044;%
DarkGray,.664,.664,.664;%
DarkGreen,0,.392,0;% <--- rgb value for DarkGreen
DarkGrey,.664,.664,.664;%
DarkKhaki,.74,.716,.42;%
DarkMagenta,.545,0,.545;%
DarkOliveGreen,.332,.42,.185;%
DarkOrange,1,.55,0;%
DarkOrchid,.6,.196,.8;%
DarkRed,.545,0,0;%
DarkSalmon,.912,.59,.48;%
DarkSeaGreen,.56,.736,.56;%
DarkSlateBlue,.284,.24,.545;%
DarkSlateGray,.185,.31,.31;%
DarkSlateGrey,.185,.31,.31;%
DarkTurquoise,0,.808,.82;%
DarkViolet,.58,0,.828;%
[...]
```